# With a fresh install of nativescript, why am I receiving an 'omnistore tincan_msg' message periodically in the console log?

Tags: logging, nativescript

I am working solely with android development on nativescript at the moment and every 15 minutes, I get a message in the console while I have `tns livesync android --watch` running:

my process.

```
tns create [new app]
```

then

```
tns platform add android
```

then

```
tns run android 
ctrl + C
tns livesync android --watch
```

everything works fine and this log occurs.

```
01-20 12:04:28.800  3386  3964 I omnistore: Connect message: queueName: tincan_msg:193303274_AXPYJSRQHKNLTJXPZM3BQDHMMSVOOTINFR6
EWMGFR2JEVAR3MHEUA, gvid: 0
```

Can anyone help explain the purpose of it or where it is coming from?
I am unable to find anything about it.

I just reinstalled node and nativescript.

```
nativescript version
2.4.2

npm version
3.10.10
```

Answer (score 2):

That's probably not related to {N} at all, just some random message popping up in your log.

Do you have an alternative appstore installed called Omnistore?

Comment: No I don't.  I've never heard of it.  I imagine I need a major reformat or something.  It just came out of nowhere, so I wanted to determine if it was nativescript based.  Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: The CLI has weird filtering in order to print out the logs you get on the Android device, and the message is a visible result of the logging behavior. Nothing to be worried about. From what I found - omnistore is somewhat related to facebook.

Comment: Ok, I began to worry based on a different log result from a com.facebook.a.a that would happen every 30 seconds. That has gone away, but I still have the omnistore thing.  I noticed it doesn't happen on another device i have.  I will open another question up for this, but perhaps you know what this log means  `Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Cl
ass<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>`  If I leave livesync running I get this re-init rejection periodically with this inside a clump of rejected re-init's.  Basically why is chromium throwing a re-init?

Comment: @DauvO this is not at all related to NativeScript. The reason you are seeing it, is because the log output is leaked through to the CLI, if you type in `adb logcat` you will see the unfiltered results, and it will be much more massive.